# Efficient method to batch-read from a lookup table

Tags: c#, performance

The following method should read all values from *source* with the indices in *keys* and store them in *destination*. For simplicity, assume that the lengths of *destination* and *keys* are equal and all indices in *keys* are >= 0 and < *source.Length*. The length of *keys* is low (<1000), the length of *source* is high (millions).

```
public static void Gather<T>(Span<T> destination, ReadOnlySpan<T> source, 
    ReadOnlySpan<int> keys)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
    {
        destination[i] = source[keys[i]];
    }
}
```

What would be an efficient method on modern hardware (SSE2, AVX2) for a mixed set of scenarios:

- keys are random
- keys are sequential
- keys are partially sequential

*Benchmark*

I usually use Benchmark.net for microbenchmarks, but i didn't find a way to flush the cpu cache between operations.

```
 class Program
 {
        public class GatherTest
        {
            private readonly int[] sequentialKeys;
            private readonly int[] partiallySequentialKeys;
            private readonly int[] randomKeys;
            private readonly int[] source;
            private readonly int[] destination;

            private const int KEYS_LENGTH = 1_000;
            private const int SOURCE_LENGTH = 10_000_000;

            public GatherTest()
            {
                var rng = new Random(0);
                this.sequentialKeys = Enumerable.Range(0, KEYS_LENGTH).ToArray();
                this.partiallySequentialKeys = Enumerable.Range(0, KEYS_LENGTH / 4).SelectMany(_ => Enumerable.Range(rng.Next(SOURCE_LENGTH - 4), 4)).ToArray();
                this.randomKeys = Enumerable.Range(0, KEYS_LENGTH).Select(_ => rng.Next(SOURCE_LENGTH)).ToArray();
                this.source = Enumerable.Range(0, SOURCE_LENGTH).ToArray();
                this.destination = new int[KEYS_LENGTH];
            }

            public static void Gather<T>(Span<T> destination, ReadOnlySpan<T> source, ReadOnlySpan<int> keys)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
                {
                    destination[i] = source[keys[i]];
                }
            }

            public static void Gather_Unnrolled<T>(Span<T> destination, ReadOnlySpan<T> source, ReadOnlySpan<int> keys)
            {
                int i = 0;
                for (; i + 4 < keys.Length; i += 4)
                {
                    destination[i] = source[keys[i]];
                    destination[i + 1] = source[keys[i + 1]];
                    destination[i + 2] = source[keys[i + 2]];
                    destination[i + 3] = source[keys[i + 3]];
                }

                for (; i < keys.Length; i++)
                {
                    destination[i] = source[keys[i]];
                }
            }

            public void FlushCache()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.source.Length; i++) _ = this.source[i];
            }

            public void Gather_Sequential()
            {
                Gather<int>(this.destination, this.source, this.sequentialKeys);
            }

            public void Gather_Sequential_Unrolled()
            {
                Gather_Unnrolled<int>(this.destination, this.source, this.sequentialKeys);
            }

            public void Gather_Random()
            {
                Gather<int>(this.destination, this.source, this.randomKeys);
            }

            public void Gather_Random_Unrolled()
            {
                Gather_Unnrolled<int>(this.destination, this.source, this.randomKeys);
            }

            public void Gather_Partially_Sequential()
            {
                Gather<int>(this.destination, this.source, this.partiallySequentialKeys);
            }

            public void Gather_Partially_Sequential_Unrolled()
            {
                Gather_Unnrolled<int>(this.destination, this.source, this.partiallySequentialKeys);
            }
            
            public void Test(Action body, string name)
            {
                var sw = new Stopwatch();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    this.FlushCache();
                    sw.Start();
                    body();
                    sw.Stop();
                }

                Console.WriteLine(name + ": " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds+" ms");
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var benchmark = new GatherTest();
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Sequential, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Sequential));
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Sequential_Unrolled, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Sequential_Unrolled));
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Partially_Sequential, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Partially_Sequential));
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Partially_Sequential_Unrolled, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Partially_Sequential_Unrolled));
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Random, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Random));
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Random_Unrolled, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Random_Unrolled));
        }
    }
```

*Output*

```
Gather_Sequential: 18.8414 ms
Gather_Sequential_Unrolled: 18.0061 ms
Gather_Partially_Sequential: 63.0309 ms
Gather_Partially_Sequential_Unrolled: 54.9459 ms
Gather_Random: 127.5608 ms
Gather_Random_Unrolled: 116.4456 ms
```

As you can see, random access is much slower than sequential access. I guess that's because an entire cpu cache line is loaded for each value copied.

Update: I tried the AVX instructions from System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86 and benchmarked the functions in two scenarios: cold (values not in cpu-cache) and warm (values already in cpu-cache).

```
class Program
    {
        public class GatherTest
        {
            private readonly int[] sequentialKeys;
            private readonly int[] partiallySequentialKeys;
            private readonly int[] randomKeys;
            private readonly int[] source;
            private readonly int[] destination;

            private const int KEYS_LENGTH = 1_000;
            private const int SOURCE_LENGTH = 10_000_000;

            public GatherTest()
            {
                var rng = new Random(0);
                this.sequentialKeys = Enumerable.Range(0, KEYS_LENGTH).ToArray();
                this.partiallySequentialKeys = Enumerable.Range(0, KEYS_LENGTH / 4).SelectMany(_ => Enumerable.Range(rng.Next(SOURCE_LENGTH - 4), 4)).ToArray();
                this.randomKeys = Enumerable.Range(0, KEYS_LENGTH).Select(_ => rng.Next(SOURCE_LENGTH)).ToArray();
                this.source = Enumerable.Range(0, SOURCE_LENGTH).ToArray();
                this.destination = new int[KEYS_LENGTH];
            }

            public static void Gather<T>(Span<T> destination, ReadOnlySpan<T> source, ReadOnlySpan<int> keys)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
                {
                    destination[i] = source[keys[i]];
                }
            }

            public static void Gather_Unnrolled<T>(Span<T> destination, ReadOnlySpan<T> source, ReadOnlySpan<int> keys)
            {
                int i = 0;
                for (; i + 4 <= keys.Length; i += 4)
                {
                    destination[i] = source[keys[i]];
                    destination[i + 1] = source[keys[i + 1]];
                    destination[i + 2] = source[keys[i + 2]];
                    destination[i + 3] = source[keys[i + 3]];
                }

                for (; i < keys.Length; i++)
                {
                    destination[i] = source[keys[i]];
                }
            }

            public static unsafe void Gather_Avx(Span<int> destination, ReadOnlySpan<int> source, ReadOnlySpan<int> keys) 
            {
                var vectorLength = Vector256<int>.Count;

                fixed (int* dst = destination)
                fixed (int* src = source)
                fixed (int* k = keys)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    for (; i + vectorLength <= keys.Length; i += vectorLength)
                    {
                        var keyVector = Avx.LoadVector256(k + i);
                        var destVector = Avx2.GatherVector256(src, keyVector, sizeof(int));
                        Avx.Store(dst + i, destVector);
                    }

                    for (; i < keys.Length; i++)
                    {
                        destination[i] = source[keys[i]];
                    }
                }
            }

            public void FlushCache()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.source.Length; i++) _ = this.source[i];
            }

            public void Gather_Sequential()
            {
                Gather<int>(this.destination, this.source, this.sequentialKeys);
            }

            public void Gather_Sequential_Unrolled()
            {
                Gather_Unnrolled<int>(this.destination, this.source, this.sequentialKeys);
            }
            
            public void Gather_Sequential_Avx()
            {
                Gather_Avx(this.destination, this.source, this.sequentialKeys);
            }

            public void Gather_Random()
            {
                Gather<int>(this.destination, this.source, this.randomKeys);
            }

            public void Gather_Random_Unrolled()
            {
                Gather_Unnrolled<int>(this.destination, this.source, this.randomKeys);
            }
            
            public void Gather_Random_Avx()
            {
                Gather_Avx(this.destination, this.source, this.randomKeys);
            }

            public void Gather_Partially_Sequential()
            {
                Gather<int>(this.destination, this.source, this.partiallySequentialKeys);
            }

            public void Gather_Partially_Sequential_Unrolled()
            {
                Gather_Unnrolled<int>(this.destination, this.source, this.partiallySequentialKeys);
            }
            
            public void Gather_Partially_Sequential_Avx()
            {
                Gather_Avx(this.destination, this.source, this.partiallySequentialKeys);
            }
            
            public void Test(Action body, string name)
            {
                this.Test(body, name + " (cold)", true);
                this.Test(body, name + " (warm)", false);
            }
            
            public void Test(Action body, string name, bool flush)
            {
                var sw = new Stopwatch();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    if (flush) this.FlushCache();
                    sw.Start();
                    body();
                    sw.Stop();
                }

                Console.WriteLine(name + ": " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds+" ms");
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var benchmark = new GatherTest();
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Sequential, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Sequential));
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Sequential_Unrolled, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Sequential_Unrolled));
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Sequential_Avx, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Sequential_Avx));
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Partially_Sequential, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Partially_Sequential));
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Partially_Sequential_Unrolled, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Partially_Sequential_Unrolled));
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Partially_Sequential_Avx, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Partially_Sequential_Avx));
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Random, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Random));
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Random_Unrolled, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Random_Unrolled));
            benchmark.Test(benchmark.Gather_Random_Avx, nameof(benchmark.Gather_Random_Avx));
        }
    }
```

*Output*

```
Gather_Sequential (cold): 18.3606 ms
Gather_Sequential (warm): 8.6091 ms
Gather_Sequential_Unrolled (cold): 16.8114 ms
Gather_Sequential_Unrolled (warm): 7.092 ms
Gather_Sequential_Avx (cold): 14.6569 ms
Gather_Sequential_Avx (warm): 2.4619 ms
Gather_Partially_Sequential (cold): 76.0622 ms
Gather_Partially_Sequential (warm): 12.1919 ms
Gather_Partially_Sequential_Unrolled (cold): 71.6684 ms
Gather_Partially_Sequential_Unrolled (warm): 8.1956 ms
Gather_Partially_Sequential_Avx (cold): 48.2327 ms
Gather_Partially_Sequential_Avx (warm): 4.2666 ms
Gather_Random (cold): 116.286 ms
Gather_Random (warm): 15.2227 ms
Gather_Random_Unrolled (cold): 109.3275 ms
Gather_Random_Unrolled (warm): 12.5555 ms
Gather_Random_Avx (cold): 110.4421 ms
Gather_Random_Avx (warm): 6.6867 ms
```

While there's no significant speedup in the 'cold' scenario, AVX really shines if all values are already in the cpu-cache. Problems that remain:

- You have to use unsafe code which may not be possible in your project
- It is not possible to have a single generic version of the function, even with *unmanaged* constraint
- The test-function here for AVX is not robust (no cpu-feature check, may fail on wrong alignment), so please don't use it in the current form

Comment: I don't see the inefficiency in the method you've shown here. What is the problem?

Comment: You're mentioning a lookup table in your title. What is the actual data structure of `source`? Is the return order important? Also, what do your benchmarks show for the current code and the three scenarios?

Comment: I don't see how you can beat constant time, O(1), for accessing indexes in an array. Also, you have to go through all the indexes in keys, so no beating linear time there.

Comment: @insane_developer depending on the data structure and the ordering of the keys, may branch prediction have an effect? Intuitively I'd say that doing the lookup in an incremental way may aid in some way (unless a hash key is involved), but that may be negated (or even negatively impacted) by the sorting of the keys. Also, array access is `address = array_start + index * element_size`, so indeed that's pretty much as O(1) as it gets

Comment: @CodeCaster maybe I'm not understanding the real requirements, but the keys being sequential or not does not make a difference, unless you want the destination to be sorted by them, in which case it will save you some processing.

Comment: AVX2 has a gather method for lookup tables, sometimes loop unrolling can help, partially sequential pattern could use System.Numerics.Vectors to copy data.

Comment: Loop unrolling etc is
 less likely to elide bounds checks, though. Have you *profiled* with vectorized versions? Avx2 is available in .net core, etc.

Comment: I tested the Avx2 instructions, but they are only available up to Vector256 (not 512). The performance gain from loop-unrolling surprises me a little bit.